# what does describe do in python?

Tags: python

I was going through code of https://github.com/hit9/CURD.py/blob/master/CURD.py which is a simple orm that performs normal curd operations .. and i could not understood part of code which goes like this(on line number 616):

```
 .....#smthing #..
 for name, attr in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
            if isinstance(attr, Field):
                attr.describe(name, cls)
                fields[name] = attr
```

what does attr.describe(attr, Field) do ? I googled it out but found nothing.

Comment: All you need to do is [learn to read the source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html), vijay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a Python language feature, it's a method on that library. You can see the definition here:

https://github.com/hit9/CURD.py/blob/master/CURD.py#L251

```
class Field(Leaf):
    """
    Field object.

    Field examples: User.name, User.age ..
    """

    def __init__(self, is_primarykey=False, is_foreignkey=False):
        self.is_primarykey = is_primarykey
        self.is_foreignkey = is_foreignkey

    # describe model's attr
    def describe(self, name, model):
        self.name = name
        self.model = model
        # fullname e.g. : User.id 's fullname is "user.id"
        self.fullname = self.model.table_name + "." + self.name
        # describe the attribute, reload its access control of writing, reading
        setattr(model, name, FieldDescriptor(self))
```

`setattr` sets an attribute on an object. So if I call `describe("field_name", myObject)`, it will set `myObject.field_name` to the description of the model. Or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a python standard thing.

The loop iterates through the names and values of a class, and the attributes of that class that are instances of a `Field` type are added to a dictionary.

`Field` is not part of python standard library, you should search that project for the `Field` class.